# Download a CSV with Restler 3rc5

Tags: php, csv, restler

I'm trying to download a CSV using Restler 3rc5.

In my index.php, I have CsvFormat set as a supported format. My API currently looks like this:

```
 /**
 * Download a CSV
 *
 * @status 200
 *
 * @url GET /downloadCSV
 * 
 */
public function downloadCSV()
{
    $array = array(
        "foo", "bar"
    );

    return $array;
}
```

When I call the API by pasting the link into my browser, a blank file is downloaded with nothing in it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying it on the browser, make sure you call the url with .csv extension.

Also make sure you have added `CsvFormat` to supported formats with

```
$r->setSupportedFormats('CsvFormat', 'JsonFormat');
```

Unlike other formats, CSV can only represent tabular data. Make sure you are returning compatible data

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found the format of array to make it available in csv export

```
$array [] = array("foo" =>"foo","bar"=>"bar","vvvv"=>"123");
```

i can able to get the array in csv format.

i hope this will be helpful to others